# Unknown regularizer: l2_cond When trying to load data from file

Tags: keras

I have been getting an error when try to load a model that I trained.

```
model_path = r'I:\\ECGMODELCP\\0.467-0.840-010-0.408-0.860.reg.hdf5'
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)





ValueError: Unknown regularizer: l2_cond
```

Ive tried

```
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'l2_cond': l2_cond(weight_matrix)})
```

But get an error of weight_matrix not defined. l2_cond is a custom kernal regularizer that I defined and depends on the weight matrix of the last layer of my model. Any help is appreciated

Comment: So your regularizer depends on data from the model you're trying to load, but the model cannot be loaded without the regularizer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already. I just loaded the weights of the model into an identical model's architecture.